# Can i use Alexa skill Reminder API and Proactive events API without AWS lambda?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, proactive

I want to integrate Proactive Event API and Reminder API into Alexa skills. I saw some examples using aws lambda. I want to know if i can use it using my own service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can yes - it's just an HTTP call so you can do that from wherever works best for your infrastructure/skill. Please refer to the documentation here:

- [Reminders API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html)
- [Proactive Events](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html)

Answer (score -1):

I would highly recommend using the [ASK SDK](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/overview.html) to develop your skill as it handles authentication for you among other things.

See this tutorial with a live code video on how to [integrate the RemindersAPI using the ASK SDK for Node.js](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/2b4de691-9cad-4c82-86e0-98e674786742/integrate-the-reminders-api-with-your-skill-to-deepen-customer-engagement1).